# Replace Text with hyperlinks

Tags: filters, content

I would like to replace few words in the content of the posts. For example.

Original:

```
Here is my test string. 
Which Need to Replace First Test word in the string.
```

Excepted String:

```
Here is my <a href="link"> test </a> string. 
Which Need to Replace First Test word in the string.
```

I have tried but there are few scenario where i have faced issues.

When that word has predefined link along with a word. Like

```
Here is my <a href="test case link"> test Case </a> string. 
Which Need to Replace First Test word in the string.
```

So my function exploded it in tow words like

```
Here is my <a href="link"> test </a> <a href="test case link"> Case </a> string.
Which Need to Replace First Test word in the string.
```

== My Solution ====

```
add_filter('the_content' , 'update_content');

function update_content($content){
        if((is_singular()){
            $termsList = array(
                 'test' => '<a href="test">test</a>'
            );

            foreach($termsList as $word => $term_link){

                //$content = str_replace($word , $replacement , $content , $count);
                //Convert into Smaller Case
                $str_content = strtolower($content);
                $str_word = strtolower($word);


                //Get the position of the word
                $position = strpos($str_content, $str_word , 0); 
                //Get the Exact word with case sensitive 
                $match_string = substr ($content , $position , strlen($word) );

                //Prepare Replacement
                $replacement = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$match_string.'</a>';


                if(!empty($position)){
                    //Replace The word
                    $content = substr_replace($content, $replacement, $position, strlen($word));
                }

            }
        }

        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? The solution you propose in your question seems to lead to a nested link, which will not work.

Comment: I have set of words with their internal link. So what i want when blog content render that if any words match from the set of the words then first match word will replace with hyper link.

Comment: I understand that. You are using the right filter and approach to do this. There seems to be a small coding error, but that's all.

Comment: Yes that what i am not able to understand .. Here is my output
$words_set = array('test'=> 'http://www.google.com');

$str = 'This is my test study. Read full test case';

After Using My Function:

$str = 'This is my <a href="http://google.com">test</a> study. Read full test case';

BUT if the link is already exist in the string then my function didn't work properly

i.e

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex PHP (rather than WP) issue if you want to take into account all possibilities.

If you replace `test` with `<a href="#">test</a>` you will run into problems if the content already has `<a href="?">test</a>`, because the result will then be `<a href="?"><a href="#">test</a></a>`

So, before you do the replace you will need to see if `test` is already a link. This is not that simple, because you cannot simply scan for `<a href="...">test</a>`. After all, you may have something like `<a href="...">this is my test, yeah!`. Or `test` may be a substring of another word, like `protesting`. To prevent the latter being targeted you might check for `test`, but then you may miss `test,`.

Another thing to consider: if there already is a link around `test`, do you want to keep that one or replace it?

So, depending on you needs you will have to build a [regular expression](https://regexr.com/) that does complex pattern recognition on your content to make sure it does exactly what you need. For help with regular expressions, [try Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regular%20expression).